# Can I make the intersection between the vertical through an `xshift`ed or `yshift`ed node and another node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, intersections, tikz-path

From [here](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#autosec-121)

> In general, the meaning of (⟨p⟩ |- ⟨q⟩) is “the intersection of a vertical line through p and a horizontal line through q”.

so `(p |- q)` makes perfectly sense in a `\path` or whatever.

At the same time, to shift a node `q` during the construction of a `\path` or whatever, say vertically, I can do `([yshift=1em]q)`.

Can I do the two things together?

`(p |- [yshift=1em]q)` and `(p |- ([yshift=1em]q))` seem to be incorrect syntaxes.

---

I know I could first `\coordinate (q2) at ([yshift=1em]q);` and then use `q2` as in `(p |- q2)`, but I was wondering if I can accomplish the same without giving intermediate names.

Comment: The implicit version of [the perpendicular coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.perpendicular) doesn't expects options in its two sub-coordinates. You could use the explicit version: `(perpendicular cs: vertical line through = {(p)},  horizontal line through = {([yshift=1em] q)})`. But for simple cases like yours, just moving the options to the start is the easier, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy in hindsight: `([yshift=1em]p |- q)` is the way to go, because we `yshift` (resp. `xshift`) the intersection node directly, which has the same effect as if we had `yshifted` the node on the side of the `-` (resp. `xshifted` the node on the side of the `|`).